# Error in packet manager after fixing nvidia-driver issues

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

So last week I made a foolish mistake of installing the wrong Nvidia drivers on my Ubuntu 20.04 and basically the GUI broke. However, I was able to fix that eventually, I thought.

Now, whenever I try using the packet-manager (apt-get) I get the following error:
[This was after running 'sudo apt-get upgrade']

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not 
installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a 
solution).
```

So, I tried what it suggested and ran 'sudo apt --fix-broken-install'. With the following errors as an output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-460 libnvidia-gl-460:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-460 libnvidia-gl-460:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
25 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/99,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 353 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 249076 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL
.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl
-460'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-
gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-460_460.32.0
3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-460:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ..
.
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/l
ibGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-
gl-460'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-li
nux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-460_460.32.0
3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-460:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So it seems to me like it is still having issues with those old nvidia-340 drivers. Has anyone come across this before or know how to fix it?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should remove diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1"
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

in case you got the same error with different libraries like : libGL.so and libEGL.so
execute the same command :

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so"
sudo dpkg-divert --remove "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so"
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```